# Wrap floated parent div's width around child image

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't wrap my head around this one. I have a div that is floated right, and image within it. The expected behavior is that the div will wrap its width around the image, and float all the way to the right. However, the div's width seems to extend past the image, which causes it to not go to the right. What am I missing to make the div wrap the width of the image?

HTML:

```
<div class='right'>
    <img src='http://www.clipartpal.com/_thumbs/pd/weather/sun_kicking_blue.png' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.right { float: right; }
img { width: 50%; }
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3D6Rv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` is wider than the `img` because you gave the `img` 50% of the width of the `div`. You can `float` the `img` right as well to get to the far right, but you will still have excessive white space to its left.

I would suggest leaving the `img` 100% width of the `div`, floating the `div` right, and just adjusting the `div`'s width.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3D6Rv/2/):

```
div.right { float: right; width: 25%; }
img { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: oh duh, I just needed to size on the div and not the image, got it. thanks

Comment: Just a side note, and also a bit of a personal preference: when writing CSS properties on one line like this, I always leave the last property's `;` off, and just have a single space between the property value and the closing `}`.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Ha, interesting. May I ask why?

Comment: @Senju, It just feels unneccesary to me to put a semicolon there, and it is not required by CSS to place one at the end of the last CSS rule in a block, so I think it just makes the code look better if it's not there.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I feel it's good practice to add it in. If you don't have it in, and you forgot that you don't have it in and you just add on more styles or push enter and add on, it will error. Making it a habit to have a semi-colon at the end will prevent this.

Comment: @kennypu Many programs which do syntax highlighting (e.g. Notepad++) will not highlight properties if the preceding property does not have a closing semicolon, making this issue easy to notice. I can understand why one would want to have it in, but as I stated, it's more of a personal preference, and I usually remember to add the semicolon in if I plan on expanding that section.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the image to 100%, it's height auto. Then set a fixed width on the wrapping div and pad it. See my updated fiddle

```
div.right { float: right;width:300px;background:#ccc;padding:10px;}
img { width: 100%; height:auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peter/3D6Rv/1/

Comment: is there a way without using fixed widths? div/image should scale.

Comment: Yes set a wrapping div which has a fixed width ie; 960px or larger. Then two nested divs each using a width by %

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply remove the css about image
and adjust it in the html page like this

```
<div><img src='http://www.clipartpal.com/_thumbs/pd/weather/sun_kicking_blue.png' style="float:right" align=right/>
```

Comment: this will result in a behavior I am not looking for. I don't want to float the image right, I want to float the div right with the image in it.